# Replace a specific pattern of text in a string with a character

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, replace, pattern-matching

I've a string like this

```
Always $1| Sometimes $27| Never $33|No Answer$0
```

I need to replace all occurance of this pattern `$ + number + |` with comma `,`

So the resulting string should be like

**Always, Sometimes,Never,No Answer**

So How can I use replace function for this purpose

I tried using

```
Dim myText as strin ="Always $1| Sometimes $27| Never $33|No Answer$0"
Regex.Replace(mytext, "\$(.+?)\|", ",")
```

But the last  $ and number keeps there. So am getting something like this

> Always,Sometimes,Never,No Answer$0

But I need to remove the ending $0 too

So the final result should be

> **Always,Sometimes,Never,No Answer**

Comment: @MattWilko Sorry..Added little more details and my try. please have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the question mark to allow for optional characters to match (the pipe character, but also spaces if that was necessary).  Does something like this work for you?

```
Dim str As String = "Always $1| Sometimes $27| Never $33|No Answer$0"
str = Regex.Replace(str, "\s?\$\d+\|?\s?", ",").TrimEnd({","c, " "c})
Console.WriteLine(str)
Console.ReadLine()
```

Output:

```
Always,Sometimes,Never,No Answer
```